# Building cURL for Cocos2d-x Eclipse, something is missing for me

Tags: eclipse, curl, cocos2d-x

There is no problem in Xcode, but in Eclipse there is unfortunately.

I did this in Android.mk:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE := game


LOCAL_MODULE_FILENAME := libgame

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := helloworld/main.cpp \
                   ../../Classes/AppDelegate.cpp \
                   ../../Classes/HelloWorldScene.cpp\
                   ../../Classes/GameplayLayer.cpp\
                   ../../Classes/swimmerc.cpp\
                   ../../Classes/pugixml.cpp

LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := ../../libs/cocos2dx \
../../libs/cocos2dx/platform \
../../libs/cocos2dx/include \
../../libs/CocosDenshion/include \
$(LOCAL_PATH)/../../Classes/\


LOCAL_WHOLE_STATIC_LIBRARIES := cocos2dx_static cocosdenshion_static curl_static

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
$(call import-module,cocos2dx)
$(call import-module,cocos2dx/platform/third_party/android/prebuilt/libcurl)
$(call import-module,CocosDenshion/android)
```

I put the `curl` folder in Classes. I then included it in `GameplayLayer.cpp`. 
No errors occur if I use

```
CURL *curl;
CURLcode res;
```

But as soon as I put

```
   curl = curl_easy_init();
```

I get an error,

```
make: *** [obj/local/armeabi/libgame.so] Error 1
```

Please help, I would gladly give one of my kidneys in exchange for getting this %&#@ to work.

I'm getting:

```
undefined reference to `curl_easy_init'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I added this line in Android.mk to make it work.

```
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := curl_static_prebuilt
```

Of course in order to connect to the internet you will also need to edit AndroidManifest.mk and add this line:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

Comment: I was missing both this and the line:

`$(call import-module,cocos2dx/platform/third_party/android/prebuilt/libcurl)`